# Mongoid greater than date or not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

I have two models

```
class Conversation
  include Mongoid::Document 

  field :last_moderated_at, type: DateTime
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```

I want to get the list of all messages that were created after the moderation date, or all of them if the moderation date is nil

I had expected the following to work

```
conversation.messages.where(
      :created_at.gte => conversation.last_moderated_at
    )
```

But apparently the comparison with nil fails (when `last_moderated_at == nil`)

Do I have no choice but to use an `if/else` or is there a mongoDB operator of type `greater than` that also works when compared to nil dates ?

EDIT : A simpler example : `Conversation.where(:created_at.gte => nil).count` will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. It does work on Mongoid version 6, at least.

Comment: It does not on Mongoid 7. When I try to do something more basic like `Conversation.where(:created_at.gte => nil).count` it will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are gonna have to to something like this:

```
conversation = Conversation.find 'some_id'

Message.where(
      conversation: conversation,
      :created_at.gte => conversation.last_moderated_at
    )
```